# Sysutcdatetime in Sql Server 2008 R2, is it deprecated?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I developed an Asp.net application that uses Entity framework to connect to a Sql Server 2008(not R2) database.
The client run the db script against a Sql server 2008 **R2** database and it executed successfully.
When the application is executed an exception is thrown:
'Sysutcdatetime' is not recognized as a built in function.
After checking the stack trace, it appeared that the exception is thrown when a LINQ to Entity framework statement is executed. The statement is something like this:

```
var item = Entities.News.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ExpirationDate > DateTime.UtcNow);
```

As far as I understand this, the generated sql statement from Entity framework uses the function Sysutcdatetime to get the current UTC date and time.
I know one of the solutions is to store the date in a variable than pass it to the lambda expression, that way the UTC date and time will be determined in the application level and hardcoded in the generated sql statement.

```
var currentUtcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
var item = Entities.News.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ExpirationDate > currentUtcDate);
```

But I am curious why the function Sysutcdatetime exists in Sql server 2008 and not in Sql server 2008 R2 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
select Sysutcdatetime()
select @@VERSION
```

Just ran that on my SQL Server and got these as the results

> 2010-07-14 19:36:40.5738642
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) -
>   10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02   Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation  Developer Edition on
>   Windows NT 5.1  (Build 2600:
>   Service Pack 3)

So as far as I can tell Sysutcdatetime still exists on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I checked using Sql server management studio on System Functions -> Date and Time Functions and it doesn't exist. I do not have access now to check again using the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

- Not in [SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(SQL.90).aspx)
- In [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(SQL.100).aspx#GetSystemDateandTimeValues)
- In [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetSystemDateandTimeValues)

Thoughts:

- What is the database compatibility level?
- Are you 100% it's SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2008?

Comment: not sure of the db compatibility level but I am pretty sure it is SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: When you get a chance run @@VERSION and see